# Count all rows from two MySQL tables in Codeigniters

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi need to count all rows in two MySQL tables.
Tables have same structure and the code I'm using in the model file is the following:

```
$this->regs_db->select ("*");
$this->regs_db->from("$this->table_images_civil, $this->table_images_military");

return $this->regs_db->count_all_results();
```

The result I'm getting is not correct at all. I know that in the first table there are 10,934 rows, in the second one there are 1,299 rows...but the result I get is 14,203,266.
What's wrong with the code above?
Thanks a lot for any hint.

EDIT: below table strusture...same for both tables
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd drop Code Igniter's DB methods. They're (in my view) obstructive and useless for anything except basic query structures.

With that in mind, you can achieve what you want with something like this:

```
$sql = '
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `'.$this->table_images_civil.'`) AS tbl1Count,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `'.$this->table_images_military.'`) AS tbl2Count';
$request = $this->regs_db->query($sql);
$arr = $request->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback Mitya. The code above return 1 as count...maybe I missed anything?

Comment: No, that should work.  You should get two columns, each containing a count from the table they represent. If that's not working, please edit the question to include your schema for the tables in question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for invaluable help and patience Mitya. In model file I'm returning the query result using return $request->result(); in controller I should have two variable: tbl1Count and tbl2Count ... but I get 0 as total so far. Updated the question on top with table structure

Comment: You're welcome. What if you don't use CI methods (as per my suggestion) and just use native MySQLi functionality? Try using my exact code above (I added a new line, to retrieve the result as an array). Run that and then run `var_dump($arr)` - anything?

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your time and hints Mitya. I'll test your code deeply and check.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->from('yourtable');
[... more active record code ...]
$query = $this->db->get();
$rowcount = $query->num_rows();
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback Hammad; your code works fine to count rows from just one table...not for multiple tables.